# How to show the first X characters and then click a href to show the rest.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

In a html view I want to show some text, but I only want to show a percentage of the whole text to the user, and if the user want to see the rest he/she needs to click a href/button. As it is now I hide the whole text.

Code for href

```
    <div>
        <h3 id="single-desc">
            <a href="#" id="AboutBtn" class="GameInfo">{$l.about_the_game}</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
```

Code for the text placement.

```
    <div hidden id="showAbout">

        <p id="AboutText">
            {$game->description}
        </p>
    </div>
```

JavaScript to toggle the text hide/show

```
$("#AboutBtn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#showAbout").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most dinamyc way!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fullText = $(".text").attr('fullText'); // get fullText attribute 
    $(".text").html(fullText.substr(0,1)); // insert only the first character from the fullText attribute 
    $("#myLink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".text").html(fullText);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="text" fullText="Fresh Fruits and Vegetables"></p>
<a href='#' id="myLink">Show Whole Text</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @davidpankov. Your solution is alright, but I want the toggleslide effect and also user can go back to only view the first X characters.

Comment: slideToggle is only for up and down slide...not to 'right' as you need